# Bean that could not be found Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest

I have a problem when trying to start my Spring Boot application with tokenization. This is my service class:

```
@Service
@Slf4j
public class JwtTokenService {
    private final JwtConfig jwtConfig;

    public JwtTokenService(JwtConfig jwtConfig) {
        this.jwtConfig = jwtConfig;
    }

    public String generateToken(Authentication authentication) {
        Long now = System.currentTimeMillis();
        return Jwts.builder()
                .setSubject(authentication.getName())
                .claim("authorities", authentication.getAuthorities().stream()
                        .map(GrantedAuthority::getAuthority).collect(Collectors.toList()))
                .setIssuedAt(new Date(now))
                .setExpiration(new Date(now + jwtConfig.getExpiration() * 1000))
                .signWith(SignatureAlgorithm.HS512, jwtConfig.getSecret().getBytes())
                .compact();
    }

}
```

This is my config class:

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@Component
public class JwtConfig {
    @Value("${security.jwt.uri:/auth/**}")
    private String Uri;

    @Value("${security.jwt.header:Authorization}")
    private String header;

    @Value("${security.jwt.prefix:Bearer }")
    private String prefix;

    @Value("${security.jwt.expiration:#{24*60*60}}")
    private int expiration;

    @Value("${security.jwt.secret:JwtSecretKey}")
    private String secret;
}
```

And I get the following error when I try to run my Application:

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Parameter 0 of constructor in services.JwtTokenService required a bean of type 'config.JwtConfig' that could not be found.


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'config.JwtConfig' in your configuration.
```

I dont understand why i get this error.

Comment: @Configuration on JwtConfig  class. Spring boot will supply a bean of JwtConfig  this class.

Comment: I still get the same error..  with @Configuration on JwtConfig

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it. The problem was that the package where the config lays was not scanned by my spring boot application. In my @SpringBootApplication I added @ComponentScan with the package where JwtConfig lays.